# how to zoom in & out in GWT

Tags: gwt

i created a widget, say MyBox, which has many other widgets. i have to use that widget on different page, however on different page, the size of the widget is different, on some page it's smaller, on other page it's bigger. Just wonder is there any way in GWT to zoom in & out the widget? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can set the width and height of a widget, and the normal kinds of "zooming" that happen with HTML will happen to your widget too.  If you want inner widgets to resize automatically, check out [Layout Panels](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels.html#LayoutPanels) in GWT 2.0 and later.